# The best way how to update a complex ViewModel on demand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime

I have `TaskViewModel` class with a lot of different properties. The simplified piece of code is below:

```
internal class TaskViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private TaskModel _model;

    public long Id
    {
        get { return _model.Id; }
        set
        {
            _model.Id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _model.Title; }
        set
        {
            _model.Title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return _model.Date; }
        set
        {
            _model.Date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Date";);
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _updateCommand;
    public RelayCommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _updateCommand
                   ?? (_updateCommand = new RelayCommand(
                       () =>
                       {
                           // somehow update _model
                       }));
        }
    }
}
```

And I have `TaskView` where I could edit the instance of `TaskViewModel`. Also I have a few validation rules, for example, if `Title`is empty I can't update model and have to reestablish previous `Title`. That's why I cannot use `"{Binding Mode=TwoWay}`. 
The question is what is the best way to update view model.
I have two ways to do it:

1. Add property of `TaskViewModel` type to the instance and bind all properties of this to the view and than using `ICommand` for updating properties in main instance if all validations rules are performing. But in this case I need to keep whole copy of object.
2. Using `"{Binding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"` for necessary properties and than in code-behind using event handlers call `binding.UpdateSource()`. But in that case I have to implement validation logic in code-behind too, which looks like a bad way in mvvm-approach.

May be you should recommend the best way for this task.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
For example of the typical validation case, `Title` mustn't be empty. If I changed the `Title` property from "Buy milk" to "Buy mi" it would be valid, but I don't want to update my model after every change of every property and save it to a storage. So I have to implement `SaveCommand` which will update the model. But also I need to have a possibility to rollback all the changes, so I can't change current view model properties directly by using `Mode=TwoWay` binding.

So the problem is how to update all changed properties on demand if they are valid?

Comment: Why can't you just use two way binding and then in your property setter do the validation, if it passes set it equal to value, otherwise, set it equal to previous value? Still new, so this may not be the best way to do this. Just trying to help.

Comment: @ProgrammingDude, thanks for your answer. Just for clarifying my problem I added a typical situation of validation in my question above.